# Speedup iteration of 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a very large numpy 2D array `M` from which I need to get all the possible submatrix that respect a limit, for every element of the array and put them in a dictionary.

I've tried with `ndenumerate` and with the double for loop, but both of them are really slow, is possible to improve?

Thanks.

*version 1*

```
poss = {}
for index, val in numpy.ndenumerate(M):
    poss[index] = [ z for z in filter(lambda t: 2*L <= sub_matrix_dim(index, t) <= H, zip(*numpy.where(M != val))) ]
```

*version 2*

```
poss = {}
for x in range(R):
    for y in range(C):
        poss[(x,y)] = [ z for z in filter(lambda t: 2*L <= sub_matrix_dim((x,y), t) <= H, zip(*numpy.where(M != M[x][y]))) ]
```

The function that is been called is:

```
def sub_matrix_dim(c1: tuple, c2: tuple): return numpy.empty((abs(c2[1] - c1[1]) + 1, abs(c2[0] - c1[0]) + 1), dtype=int).size
```

**Edit**
For example from this 2d array:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

with `L = 1` and `H = 6` in `poss{}` I'll have:

```
{
 (0, 0): [(1, 1), (1, 2)],
 (0, 1): [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
 (0, 2): [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)],
 ...
 (1, 1): [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)],
 ...
 (2, 1): [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)], 
 (2, 2): [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)], 
 (2, 3): [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3)], 
 (2, 4): [(1, 2), (1, 3)]
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'respect a limit'? Maybe there's a vectorized way to write this code that would be much faster.

Comment: My 2d array is only made of zeros and ones, and for every element of the array I need to find all the possible submatrix that have a size between `2*L` and `M`, where `L` and `M` are integers defined early in the code. In particular all the submatrix "starts" and "ends" in opposite elements, that is why I used `zip(*numpy.where(M != M[x][y]))`.

Comment: Do you include overlapping submatrices?

Comment: Yes. Only after I select the most suitable for the application.

Comment: In my previous comment I made a mistake, the dimension must be included in `2*L` and `H`, not `M`; where `H` is an integer. Sorry.

Comment: Can you give some **simple** input and expected output data?

Comment: The small example really helps, but can you also say what are typical values for shape(M), L and H? Also how many different (unique) values are in M?

Comment: Typically `M` has 200/300 rows and columns, `L` is usually 1 and `H` is at most 10. In `M` there are only two unique values.

Answer (score 0):

I may be going in the completely wrong direction here, but won't this work?

```
def sub_matrix_dim(c1: tuple, c2: tuple): return (abs(c2[1] - c1[1]) + 1)) * (abs(c2[0] - c1[0]) + 1)
```

Comment: It doesn't work because in `poss[(r, c)]` it puts a "subarray" of `M`, but I need to have the indexes of all the elements of M, with a value different from the value of `M[r, c]`, that could create a "suitable" sub-matrix.  Also `2*L` and `H` aren't related directly to the number of rows and columns, but to the number of cells of the sub-matrix (look at the function `sub_matrix_dim` in my original post). I hope I explained myself well :/

Comment: Yes, they're the dimensions of the sub-matrices right? I updated my answer.

Comment: Works better than before, but the use of `dim_r` and `dim_c` isn't right for my case. I edited my original post with an example.

Comment: What do you want to do at the edges? Because in your example, `H.shape = (3, 5)` but `H = 6`, so there should be no submatrices.

Comment: I'd really recommend you stay away from tuples like the ones in your example, instead store row and column indices. Tuples for every index can be very slow. Also, I've updated my answer.

Comment: What? `M` has 15 elements, and I need all the possible sub-matrix with at least 2 elements because `2*L = 2` and at most 6 elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164392/discussion-between-hameer-abbasi-and-facosenpai).